# Using app id from paypal

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to add donate into my application. I went through tutorial and did the coding. But the real problem is how to get the app id. I have an account in developer.paypal.com and I tried creating an application in that one and got an app id. But I doubt if I add that id to app, will the money go to the recipient which is set in 'setRecipient' or the one who got the app id. What is the actual use of app id. Should the mechant need to get the app id. Please help me to understand this. I went through many documentation, but didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The APP-ID is to give the account submitting the API call permission to use that specific call. Who you define as the receiver is where the money goes.

What API call are you trying to use? Have you tested this in the Sandbox at all? There is a sandbox APP-ID you can use - APP-80W284485P519543T

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Yes I've used sandbox. I'm thinking of making it live.

Comment: To make it live you'll need to go to Developer.PayPal.com, the applications tab, and then follow the steps from the "Create and manage Classic API apps" link.

Comment: @paypal_Patrick I generated the Live App id but now it is showing message "Login Failed, please try after sometime" on login with original paypal credentials

Comment: Are you getting that error while trying to sign into an account to complete a payment? Are you using the Live or Sandbox site for testing? Or is it a problem with Developer.PayPal.com?